# How to increment a value of column by 1 depends on last value row in mariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a mysql table like this and I use mariaDB  :

[image]

I hope to increment id_subjekta by one instead of null like this:

```
|id_subjekata|
     1
     2
     3
     4 
   .....
```

I do something like that but is not working :

```
REPLACE INTO `mape` (`id`, `naziv_subjekta`, `id_subjekta`, `predlozak`, `sifra`,       `naziv`, `opis`, `izradio`, `izradio_id`, `status`, `zakljucak`, `uvodno_o_obvezniku`, `izjava_o_ciljevima`, `sadrzaj`, `redni_broj`, `revizija_broj`, `revizija_datum`, `kontrolirao`, `kontrolirao_id`, `datum_kontrole`, `odobrio_id`, `odobrio`, `datum_odobrenja`, `datum_izrade`, `izradio_funkcija`, `kontrolirao_funkcija`, `odobrio_funkcija`, `tip`, `vrste_organizacijskih`, `suzbijanje_korupcije`, `isu`, `popis`, `popis_tablica`, `popis_grafickih_prikaza`, `popis_slika`, `upravljanje_kvalitetom`, `original_id`, `country`) VALUES
 (%s, %s, (SELECT MAX(id_subjekta) + 1  FROM id_subjekta, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);
```

but that's give me errors or I do like this :

```
Update mape Set id_subjekta = id_subjekta + 1;
```

that increment value but all with same values "1"!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add trigger for marriadb for the `INSERT`

This will automatically increment the value by 1 from the previous value. It will happen on each insert. If there is no value, it will default to 0 and then add 1, making 1, this happens in case of null values, such as

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER increment_value
AFTER INSERT ON mape
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE prev_value INT;
    
    SELECT id_subjekta INTO prev_value
    FROM mape
    WHERE id = NEW.id - 1;
    
    IF prev_value IS NULL THEN
        SET prev_value = 0;
    END IF;
    
    UPDATE mape
    SET id_subjekta = prev_value + 1
    WHERE id = NEW.id;
END;
```

**Details**

In the context of database triggers, `NEW` is a keyword that represents the newly inserted or updated row being processed by the trigger. It allows you to access the values of the columns in the new row.

When an `AFTER INSERT` trigger is fired, the `NEW` keyword refers to the newly inserted row, and you can use it to reference the values of columns in that row.

Comment: @user22242313 just copy and paste this sql command into your query windows in your sql manager.... then it will automatically take care of your issue

Comment: I get this error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5?

Comment: @user22242313 apologies, I've corrected the sql code

Comment: @user22242313 if you are happy with this solution, remember to upvote and mark it as the answer. have a joyful weekend.